# Square of value VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

How do i write a program that square the value in the textbox and add it in the listbox each time the button is click. from 0 to 100000. thanks
This is what I have so far
Public Class frmSquare

```
Private Sub btnGo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    Dim x As Double
    Dim number As Double = txtNumber.Text

    lstSquare.Items.Add(number * number)
    x = number

End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What's happening now? It looks like it should at least be doing that. Note that you should try and parse the value in the text box to make sure its numeric first and doesn't look like you have a reason to store into a variable x.

Comment: Yes it does but what I want it to keep squaring the new value, when I clicked the button for the second timee. for example I start with 2: I will have 4,16,... in the listbox.

Comment: `x = Math.pow(number,2) lstSquare.Items.add(x) txtNumber.Text = x`

Comment: Thanks very much man. I just have to lay it properly but it is working fine

Comment: I'll post this as an answer when I'm back at my computer (using cell now) but you also need to check that the value entered is actually a number. You can use the TryParse method of the double class. Otherwise you will get exceptions thrown if someone enters non numeric text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way to do this, hope this helps:

```
If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
            Dim dbl As Double = CDbl(TextBox1.Text)
            dbl *= dbl
            ListBox2.Items.Add(dbl)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Value entered is not a Number")
        End If
```